# How do I give my root partition (/dev/sda9) all the unallocated space?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted

I'm runing Linux Mint 19 on a Lenovo z70 Laptop. After shrinking my Windows volume so I can give my linux volume more space, I opened Gparted to find it more complicated than I'd thought. I want to give /dev/sda9 (my root partition) 220 GB from the unallocated drive. Here's a screenshot:
*(the image uploaded wont let me select photos so I used imgur)*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6uyM.png

**EDIT** It seems like I can shrink my Windows volume even more: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpGtN.png 
 So I want to shrink it down to that size and then put as much storage as I can to my sda9 drive. When I select resize, however, the most it will let me add is aprox 10 GB. What I want to do is add 400 GB to the storage of my root directory. I'm not sure how to do this and I'm asking here because this isn't something I'm comfortable *messing around with* excatly. Thanks for your patience since I'm a newbie with linux and partitions.

Comment: There's no need to add that space into sda9 in order to use it. You can simply create a new partition and filesystem and then mount it under under your root filesystem.

Comment: Why didn't gparted work? Should be really basic, just move & resize sda9, what went wrong? (If you don't want to do the probably slow moving of sda9, then another partition is a quick & easy option, having a separate home/data partition has benefits)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing. When I try and resize it it just says its going to grow it by 10 GB, then it selects the unallocated space. This is what I see before I press apply (which I haven't done yet): http://i.imgur.com/pWinV1p.png

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: Your `gparted` screen-shot shows that you are trying to edit a running partition. You need to use a Live Boot disc: you can then expand `sda9` above and below.

Answer (score 2):

gparted should have no trouble doing either of these options, but booting from a live linux *might* be required to move the `/` partition.

To enlarge sda9, it looks like you just need to:

1. Move sda9 to the left as far as it will go (putting all the free space on it's right)
2. Then enlarge sda9 to the right

For shrinking Windows partitions, you might want to use Windows itself, it's more adept at handling ntfs, but I think gparted can give it a try anyway.

Implied is step zero: always have a backup of any important data.

Comment: sorry, but how do I move it to the left? When I select "Resize/Move" it just opens a resize dialogue.

Comment: I think the problem is that it is to the right of the 400 GB unallocated space. I dont see how I can move it to the left.

Comment: The dialog should be fairly straight forward, it even has a graphical area where you can click on & drag the partition boundaries if I recall. The unallocated space doesn't really move (it's like empty space on a shelf), you just move the partition to the left, into the empty space, then enlarge the partition

Comment: I'm sorry but it simply does not give me that option. I can move the Windows Partition but sda9 does not give me that option. I'll try booting from a live linux.

Comment: Most likely it doesn't want to move the mounted root partition, should have no problems running live when the partition's not mounted (can be umount-ed). There's even video tutorials like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=62&v=zwNiNNYg55U

Comment: I’m doing it from parted live now: https://i.postimg.cc/t4Hp6fLT/8-F0-D54-F6-AFCF-450-F-B47-F-DCE3469-AB639.jpg

Comment: If it worked, and this answer helped, then marking a correct answer would be good :)